# How to test aluminum polymer capacitor for failure?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, failure

I'm not electric engineer, so maybe it is obvious, but I would like to know how do I test (in-circuit) aluminum polymer capacitor for failure? Electrolytic capacitor usually fail with easily visible damage to the aluminum case but polymer one (as I understand) look intact even in case of catastrophic failure.

Comment: I have just run into a huge problem ( company wide) with aluminum-polymer capacitors. If they are slightly overvoltaged they lose their capacitance above DC and their ESR starts to skyrocket. I've taken them apart and there is no visible damage. LCR meter with cap off the board is fastest way to check. Stay away from them.. they are really bad news and are going to cost my company tens of millions of dollars in warranty and rework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technicians often use an ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance) meter, which works in-circuit and will find open parts.

You can usually test in-circuit for shorts with an ohmmeter.

Testing is done with the power off and after discharging the capacitor in both cases, of course.

One crude test you can do if the cap is not shorted (to check for "open" or high ESR) is to parallel it (tack it on with a soldering iron) with a known-good capacitor and see if the circuit starts working. Only do this if you understand enough about the circuit to be sure it won't hurt anything.

Comment: ohmmeter sounds good, is that mean that failed cap should be shorted and if it is not does it necessary means it is ok?

Comment: No, it could also be open (or have high ESR). Both tests are necessary.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks! And another question, since I cannot identify the cap manufacturer I don't have tech specs.  how do I figure ESR numbers?

Comment: How do you know it's aluminum polymer? You can compare similar sizes and values of parts using a parametric search on (for example) digikey.com to get a rough idea.

Comment: just saw your edit with parallel capacitor, I can easily ruin the pcb :) but in any case, should I consider something but polarity?

Comment: Definitely consider polarity (value, voltage rating, of course). Some (not many) power supply circuits might not like double the capacitance. Usually tolerance is -20/+80% and usually the caps are on the low side, so it's not far out of spec. I mention this because some DC-DC converters are pretty fussy about capacitive load.